# Complex a little bit (attendance) MYSQL QUERY

Tags: mysql

I have spent the last 24hrs figuring how things will work.

I have three table(employeeAttendance, employeeInfor, employeeExcuse)

employeeAttendace this gives the record of all attendance made on that (EmployeeNo,Date)
employeeInfor this gives the complete record of employee information (Name, Dept etc)
employeeExcuse this gives a reason for absence when attendance is not upto requirement.

```
SELECT employeeAttendance.EmployeeNo, COUNT(employeeAttendance.EmployeeNo ) AS `att`,
  CASE att when>20 then(select attreason from employeeExcuse) 
    else 'explanation' 
  END AS Remarks 
FROM employeeAttendance 
INNER JOIN employeeInfor ON employeeAttendance.EmployeeNo = employeeInfor.EmployeeNo 
GROUP BY employeeAttendance.attyear 
ORDER BY employeeAttendance.attmonth;
```

this code will give a *HINT*. My problem is i have joined employeeAttendance and employeeInfor, is working perfectly, the main issue is i want to join table employeeExcuse when employee attendance is less than requirement (let say 10) so as to check if he has an excuse days otherwise there need for an explanation

*ERROR*

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '>20 then(select att from employeeExcuse) else 'explanation' END AS Remarks' at line 1
```

Comment: You are also going to have trouble with your sub-select.  You're using no discriminator.  It breaks the moment employeeExcuse contains more than one row.

Comment: You're also not grouping on employeeAttendance.EmployeeNo, even though you're selecting it from your query.